# Dimension of space of meromorphic functions on torus with only one pole

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

I've distilled this down to just the most necessary details in order to avoid cluttering this question. Let $\Gamma$ be some lattice in $\mathbb{C}$. Let, say, $V$ denote the space of meromorphic functions on the torus $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ with exactly one (possibly removable) singularity at a certain fixed point $x \in V$ such that, if $f \in V$ then the order of its pole (if there is one) at $x$ is at most $n$. Then apparently the dimension of this space is $n$. I really don't see how - apparently one would have to use the Weierstrass $\wp$-function to understand that....could anybody please provide a bit of guidance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume that the pole is at $z=0$. A function
$f \in V$ has a Laurent-series
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{j=-n}^\infty a_n z^n
$$
at $z=0$.

Now consider the Weierstrass $\wp$ function for the same lattice, and
its derivatives $\wp', \ldots, \wp^{(n-2)}$.
$\wp, \wp', \ldots, \wp^{(n-2)}$ have poles at $z=0$
of order $2, 3, \ldots, n$, respectively. It follows that for suitable constants
$c_0, \ldots, c_{n-2}$,
$$
g(z) = f(z) - c_0 \wp - c_1 \wp' - \ldots - c_{n-2} \wp^{(n-2)}
$$
has at most a simple pole at $z=0$ (and no other poles in the
fundamental parallelogram).

And since the sum of all residues of an elliptic function in the fundamental parallelogram is always zero, $g$ has no pole at all
and therefore is *constant.*

It follows that functions in $V$ are exactly the linear combinations
$$
 c + c_0 \wp + c_1 \wp' + \ldots + c_{n-2} \wp^{(n-2)}
$$
with $c, c_0, \ldots, c_{n-2} \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation; thank you. I just have one stupid question - how do we not lose generality by assuming that the pole is at the origin?

Comment: @ActonGrey: By considering $f(z-z_0)$ instead of $f$.

Comment: I have a rather vague question (sorry!). I am reading a bit about meromorphic functions on the torus and the Weierstrass function keeps coming up, what is so special about it? Can't we consider another one, such as $\sum_{w\in \mathbb{Z}^2}(-1)^{w_1+w_2}\frac{1}{z-w}$? (in analogy with $1/\sin(z)$)? Or $\sum_w
(1/f(z-w))$ for some other choice of $f$?

Comment: @kaleidoscop: The Weierstrass function is in some sense the *simplest* non-constant elliptic function, with one pole (of order 2) in the fundamental parallelogram. Every elliptic function can be expressed as a rational function of $\wp$ and $\wp'$.

Comment: Just read this answer, and I want to comment that there is a small mistake: $\wp', \ldots \wp^{(n-2)}$ have poles of order $3, \ldots, n$, respectively, which validates that we can choose such constants.

Comment: @DWe1: You are right, thank you for letting me know!